# Extracting folder name from file through iteration - slow

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a program where I need to loop throughout the files and sub-directories. I need to extract the subfolder name where the has been extracted.

I have a dictionary that contains all the subfolders names that I need to work with, `d`. Then by iterating through the files, I need to check if their director is in d or not.

Here is my code:

```
d = {'folder_1': 'a', 'folder_2': 'b', 'folder_3': 'c'}
dir_path = "/Users/user_1/Desktop/images_testing"

for root, directories, files in os.walk(dir_path):
                for filename in files:
                    filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
                    temp_path = os.path.dirname(filepath)
                    temp_sub_dir = temp_path.split("/")
                    if temp_sub_dir[-1] in d:
                        #do some work
```

This works fine but SUPER slow. Is there any way to make this process faster? It is super slow. 
My main problem is on these lines:

```
temp_path = os.path.dirname(filepath)
temp_sub_dir = temp_path.split("/")
```

I do not need the full path, I just need the folder name where this file came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about do that like this:

```
for root, directories, files in os.walk(dir_path):
    temp_sub_dir = os.path.basename(root)
    if temp_sub_dir in d:
        for filename in files:
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)                    
            #do some work
```

Answer (score 0):

As you 'walk' through check whether the current directory is one of those listed in `d`. If it is and if the file in this dictionary location is in the current directory then 'do something'. Seems simpler.

```
import os 

d = {'folder_1': 'a', 'folder_2': 'b', 'folder_3': 'c'}
dir_path = "/Users/user_1/Desktop/images_testing"

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(dir_path):
    if os.path.split(dirpath) in d and d[os.path.split(dirpath)] in files:
            #do some work
```